# "&" operator in a conditional statement

Tags: php

I found this bunch of code in Services_JSON php library:

```
if ($this->use & SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE) {
    $stk = array(SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ);
    $obj = array();
} else {
    $stk = array(SERVICES_JSON_IN_OBJ);
    $obj = new stdClass();
}
```

My question is about the first line. What does the single **"&"** operator do?

Comment: RTM -  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: It is a bitwise operator, not a logical operator. It operates on the data at a binary level, which gives you a lot of power, but please don't confuse it with the logical AND operator, `&&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the PHP bitwise `AND` operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 0):

&& means "and"  (logical operator) but a single "&" is a bitwise operator that does a binary comparison of the bits.

Here is the manual from php.net:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain not only what & does but what this bitwise-and operator is probably used for in this case take a look at

```
<?php
define('SOME_FLAG', 1);
define('SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE', 2);
define('ANOTHER_FLAG', 4);

foo(0);
foo(7);
foo(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE|ANOTHER_FLAG);

function foo($value) {
    echo "foo($value)\n";

    bar($value, SOME_FLAG);
    bar($value, SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
    bar($value, ANOTHER_FLAG);

    if ( $value & SOME_FLAG ) {
        echo "  SOME_FLAG set\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "  SOME_FLAG NOT set\n";
    }

    if ( $value & SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE ) {
        echo "  SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE set\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "  SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE NOT set\n";
    }

    if ( $value & ANOTHER_FLAG ) {
        echo "  ANOTHER_FLAG set\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "  ANOTHER_FLAG NOT set\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
} 

function bar($value, $flag) {
    printf("  value|  %08s (%d)\n", decbin($value), $value);
    printf("  flag |& %08s (%d)\n", decbin($flag), $flag);
    printf("  and  |= %08s (%d)\n", decbin($value & $flag), $value & $flag);
    echo "\n";
}
```

the output is

```
foo(0)
  value|  00000000 (0)
  flag |& 00000001 (1)
  and  |= 00000000 (0)

  value|  00000000 (0)
  flag |& 00000010 (2)
  and  |= 00000000 (0)

  value|  00000000 (0)
  flag |& 00000100 (4)
  and  |= 00000000 (0)

  SOME_FLAG NOT set
  SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE NOT set
  ANOTHER_FLAG NOT set

foo(7)
  value|  00000111 (7)
  flag |& 00000001 (1)
  and  |= 00000001 (1)

  value|  00000111 (7)
  flag |& 00000010 (2)
  and  |= 00000010 (2)

  value|  00000111 (7)
  flag |& 00000100 (4)
  and  |= 00000100 (4)

  SOME_FLAG set
  SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE set
  ANOTHER_FLAG set

foo(6)
  value|  00000110 (6)
  flag |& 00000001 (1)
  and  |= 00000000 (0)

  value|  00000110 (6)
  flag |& 00000010 (2)
  and  |= 00000010 (2)

  value|  00000110 (6)
  flag |& 00000100 (4)
  and  |= 00000100 (4)

  SOME_FLAG NOT set
  SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE set
  ANOTHER_FLAG set
```

It's a way to test if a certain flag is set in a value.
Take a look at the php documentation, e.g. the documentation of of [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
 flags
    Can be a combination of the following flags [...]
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [...]
    PREG_SET_ORDER [...]
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE [...]
```

You will will find this `Can be a combination of the following flags...` thing many times in the documentation. And the code behind those functions/methods does exactly the kind of checking using the bitwise-and operator.